# Why does deploying an application to Amazon beanstalk create a new security group and a new EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm testing nerddinner on aws Amazon ec2.

I have created security group (`mygroup`) and an Amazon ec2 instance (with security group `mygroup`)

I have followed the steps in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-N0z5K_WFI

After I have published an application to aws using Amazon beanstalk, I've found in aws management console that a new security group and a new ec2 instance have been added.

Why? How can I force my application to be published in the first ec2 instance that I have created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk creates and manages its own servers. It won't use ones you've set up manually.

Comment: which one i should use to achieve that(load balancing?)